# Sequential generation of any random graph

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, markov-chains, random-walks, random-graphs

The high-level question is: can we generate any random graph with size $d$ using a Markov chain?

For example, let $X^{(0)} = (1,0,\ldots,0) \in R^d$ be the initial state, and $X^{(t+1)} = f^{(t)}(X^{(t)}, \epsilon^{(t)})$, where $\{\epsilon^{(t)}\}_{t=0}^\infty$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. After $(d-1)$ iterations, we use $Z = \{X^{(0)},\ldots, X^{(d-1)}\}\in R^{d\times d}$ to construct a graph, whose adjacency matrix is, say, $(Z + Z')/2$.

In specific, can all random graphs, e.g., Erdos-Renyi graph and stochastic block model, be constructed in this way (ideally, with a relatively simple $\{f^{(t)}\}_{t=0}^\infty$)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  The correspondence between $X^{(t)}$ and $f$ and $\varepsilon$ is a bit unclear to me.  But this seems to be the edge-exposure model, which is very important for a lot of applications.  In particular, you can use this sort of model to cook up lots of useful martingales.  Alon and Spencer has a good bit on this.  For instance, see the sections on concentration of chromatic number.

Comment: @PatDevlin Thanks a lot for the pointer! So basically $X^{(t)}$ corresponds to a column in the adjacency matrix (before post-processing), $f^{(t)}$ is the "generator" for the column-wise generation, and $\epsilon^{(t)}$ is the injected randomness.

Comment: Then in that case, if you're building the matrix one column at a time, this is the vertex-exposure model.

Comment: @PatDevlin I checked out the vertex-exposure model. It seems very related. Thanks again for the pointer!

Comment: You can get Erdos-Renyi graphs by making $f^{(t)}$ ignore its first argument and generate a random 0/1 partial column by ignoring all but the first $t$ entries of a random $d$-vector $\epsilon^{(t)}$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Thanks for the reply! I totally agree with you. I think the more difficult case is structural graphs like stochastic block model. I am very curious about how to generate such structures sequentially.

Comment: I think you can sort of cheat, if the $X$'s are allowed to be real valued.  You could certainly get any distribution if you were allowed long-term memory.  But you could, for instance, encode the values of $X^{(1)}, \dots, X^{(i-1)}$ with an appropriate real number in the $i+1$ entry of $X^{(i)}$.  Then you choose $X^{(i+1)}$ with an $i$th entry that cancels out the encoded value after symmetrization, and with a new code in its $i+2$th entry.

Comment: If the $X$s were required to be $\{0,1\}$ valued, or upper triangular, or something, then maybe a model where, say, vertex 5 was required to be isolated, could give you trouble.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes I think you are right. I think we somehow need to restrict the information $X^{t}$ gets from the previous iterates.